# Creating new database in code, RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm running RavenDB.Client 2.0.2173-Unstable.  I'm creating a multi-tenant system, and as part of my registration process, i would like to create a new Raven database.

I have three simple lines of code..

```
  string newDBName = "1234";
  IDocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://myserver:8080",    DefaultDatabase = newDbName};
  documentStore.Initialize();
  documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(newDBName);
```

Per suggestion, I also tried this:

```
  string newDBName = "1234";
  IDocumentStore documentStore = new DocumentStore { Url = "http://myserver:8080"};
  documentStore.Initialize();
  documentStore.DatabaseCommands.EnsureDatabaseExists(newDBName);
```

I get an InvalidOperationException on the last line, Raven is telling me it could not figure out what to do.

```
<h1>Could not figure out what to do</h1>

        <p>Your request didn't match anything that Raven knows to do, sorry...</p>
```

I know my connection/server works, because I'm able to read/write from the default database.

Is it a permissions issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create a database from the database you're already in. Leave the DefaultDatabase field blank so you connect to the RavenDB system database.  You should then be able to create the new tenant database.

You should also make sure to pass the tenant database name when opening sessions, creating indexes, and using DatabaseCommands.

Comment: hi Matt.  I tried that as well, getting the same error. the inner exception is some HTTP 400 error if that helps. It keeps failing on EnsureDatabaseExists. I can pass any string in there and it will still fail.  I can interact with the default database just fine.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  Is your server also the same release of raven?

Comment: The internal API for creating databases changed around rev 2033.  If your server is earlier than that, it would explain the error.

Comment: that was indeed why it wasn't working. updated server to 2173 as well, and now all is good.  thanks matt!

Answer (score 2):

In Ravendb v4, you can use the *[CreateDatabaseOperation](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.0/csharp/client-api/operations/server-wide/create-database)* to create a new database on the server.

```
store.Maintenance.Server.Send(
         new CreateDatabaseOperation(new DatabaseRecord("MyNewDatabase")));
```